# Difference between using the DIRECT_READ and EXPORT in Apache Beam's BigQueryIO

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm running into some performance issues in the Apache Beam pipeline I'm building when I try to read from BigQuery using the typical BigQueryIO library. Reading through [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#storage-api) docs, I've noticed that it offers two different ways of reading from BQ: the EXPORT and DIRECT_READ method. However, it doesnt indicate the benefits of one over the other, so I wanted to see if there are any associated to choosing DIRECT_READ over the default EXPORT.

Comment: What are the performance issues? One reason we switched to DIRECT_READ was that we were hitting the ExtractBytesPerDay quota.

Comment: We were seeing 200k record read take 20-25 mins. In Spark it would be done in 2-3 mins. At this point I tried that, and also moving away from TableRow format but it's still too slow